# How can I update an Entity in Symfony 4 and API Platform

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm using Symfony 4 with API Platform and I altered my existing Entity by adding some fields to it by running:

```
php bin/console Make:Entity
```

again.
After that I ran:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

and:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Then I copied the Entity and the Repository to the Server and cleaned the cache there also.
After that I altered the SQL Table directly in the database reflecting the same as on my local side (where I ran migration).

When I now open my Swagger Documentation by travelling to /symfonysite/api/ on the server,
I can see the model altered correctly but the route examples (if you click on a route) does not reflect that.
Also when I do a GET Request with Postman, it's only returning the old Entity reflecting the old Model without the new added fields.

Can you point me out what is missing ?
What is your way to alter an Entity on production site?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally got it, it was very simple.
To reflect the new model in the result, i had to add a group to my entity fields. Since its a get request i had to add the group "get" in the annotations

```
@Groups({"get"})
```

When i asked the question, my entity looked like this:

```html
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;
```

Finally i fixed it by changing it to this

```html
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    private $firstname;
```